# Prevent field from suggesting previously used word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, input, autosuggest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I have a doubt about running a script in JavaScript.

Let's say that I entered in a form "Hello World". Days latter I come back to the same form using the same machine and I'm going to type "Hello World" again, but when I type "H", the word "Hello World" pops up already.

I don't remember setting anything in my script to have that functionality. I searched through it all but I don't see anything that may be causing that behavior.

What do I have to remove to make it stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's autocomplete.

It comes by default, you don't have exactly to "remove it" but to turn it off.

It'll be something like this:

```
<input ... autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Oh, it was so simple that I don't know if I say "thank you" or "sorry".

Comment: A doubt is a doubt. You're welcome.